# Why is my react web app return 500 after google login and data mapping is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-google-login, after successfully logging in, I call onSuccess to responseGoogle, get access token, then fetch API with the new token.
After that, I setState to my list to render it below:

```
responseGoogle = response => {
        console.log(response);
        const tokenBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(
            {access_token: response.accessToken},
            null, 2)],
            {type: 'application/json'});

        fetch(API URL here, {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + response.accessToken,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(
                this.state),
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        access: response.accessToken,
                        companyList: result.companyList,
                    });
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                    });
                }
            )
        console.log(response.accessToken);
    };
```

After that, I just render it to a dropdown list:

```
render() {
    const {companyList} = this.state;

    return (
        <div className="Login">
            <Col>
                <Card className="text-center">
                    <Card.Header as="h3">Login</Card.Header>
                    <br/>
                    <Form>
                        <GoogleLogin className="text-center"
                                     clientId=//CLIENTID
                                     buttonText="LOGIN WITH GOOGLE"
                                     name={"googleToken"}
                                     onClick={this.handleChange}
                                     onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
                                     onFailure={this.responseGoogleFail}
                        />
                        <br/>
                        <br/>

                        {/*{access &&*/}
                        {companyList.map(companyList => (
                            <Dropdown>
                                <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
                                    Please choose a company
                                </Dropdown.Toggle>

                                <Dropdown.Menu>

                                    <Dropdown.Item>{companyList.name}</Dropdown.Item>

                                </Dropdown.Menu>

                            </Dropdown>
                        ))}
                        {/*}*/}
                    </Form>
                    <br/>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        </div>
    );
}
```

the API was designed by my group's leader, as the google login set as POST and after require request googleToken: "string", it will respond with the company list I want.
I planned on using inline conditional rendering for when after I got the list, but that doesn't matter now.
It seems that I have made some major mistake around here and couldn't figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, the backend that processes the token from google requires tokenId not accessToken, and also, the authorization doesn't need 'Bearer', 
so it should be this:

```
Authorization: response.tokenId,
```